# How to fix "detached entity passed to persist" during posting new User?

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

I have a Spring boot starter data JPA application with a MapStruct

Here is my Role entity

```
public class Role {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String name;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String description;
}
```

Here is my User entity

```
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

...

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "roleId")
  private Role role;
}
```

Here is my migration chageset for Liquibase

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: users
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: SERIAL
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
...
              - column:
                  name: role_id
                  type: INT
                  constraints:
                    references:
                      tableName: roles
                      columnNames: id
```

There are only 2 roles (Admin and User).
Each user can only have one role.

When a new user posts, I get an error

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.myapp.entity.User] with root cause

org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.myapp.entity.User

I tried to change the mapper, changed the CascadeType in ManyToOne annotation.

Comment: replace private int id = Integer.MAX_VALUE; with private Long id; Hibernate thinks this max value is a valid id and fails

Comment: I can’t even imagine where Integer.MAX_VALUE came from. 
I removed them from both entities and it helped. Thanks a lot, that was a stupid mistake.